# Unity menus and fonts weird rendering

Tags: unity, 14.04, ati, fonts, window-manager

I have an issue that occurs occasionally on my Ubuntu 14.04 (x64).
Sometimes, right when I turn on my pc, the font and windows are messy. But, if I log out and log on Guest Account, everything works perfectly. When i try to log back on my account, everything works great again. But I have to do it quite frequent.

Any ideas?

Here are some screenshots:
[image: Menus shouldn't be appearing]

[image: Chrome windows are rendering incorrectly]

Thanks!